# How to stop Hindi language Character or Symbol '।' Converting into HTML Entity Code on blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape-characters

I am using the below script to convert "." into "।" which is the Hindi stop symbol. I am using this code in a blogger post, The script code converts this dot (.) symbol into HTML entity code on blogger post and gives me code like below

```
&#2404;
```

When I am using pipe | in place of ।, it works perfectly and there is no error. But pipe "|" is not the right symbol for a full stop in Hindi.

Kindly suggest converting "." into "।" that is for a blogger like similar code

Please correct me If I am wrong. I don't have much knowledge of JavaScript and Jquery.

I have used some below code and it works here fine but it did not work on the platform [Blogger](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html)

Please suggest me the appropriate solution

```
<!doctype html>
<html dir='ltr' lang='en-GB'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test page</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var str = val.replace('.', '।');
        $(this).val(str);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you encode to and decode from Base64 you don't lose any characters that can be used and you will support more characters than just '|' without having to add more replaceAll functions.

Comment: @Emil Karlsson,
Please provide the appropriate code

Comment: @Emil Karlsson,
this Code works Fine to convert '.' into '।'. except [Blogger](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html) Please suggest the appropriate code, I don't have much knowledge of Coding

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7,
this Code works Fine and also on StackOverflow to convert '.' into '।'  except [Blogger](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html) I have added the code [here](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html) Please check the [link](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html)  and provide the appropriate code, I don't have much knowledge of Coding